# How can I play looping music in the background as other functions are being performed?

Tags: python, subprocess

I am currently using the `subprocess` module to play .mp3 files. It works just fine getting them to play, but once I do `subprocess.call(["afplay", "../music/songname.mp3"])`, that's all the code will do until the entire duration of the song has finished playing. I want to make things happen *while* the song is playing. I don't know how easy this is but I've struggled to find people online asking about the same thing. Is it possible to use a different command with the same `subprocess` module and achieve this result? Is there a completely separate way to achieve this? I'm open to anything, but keep in mind I'm very new to this.

I have created a loop track so that, after a certain time in the song has been reached, it will instead play an identical track which has set beginning and end times that, when played back-to-back, create a perfect music loop. Once that first problem is solved, how can I rig this track to repeat infinitely in the background?

I'm very new to this.

Comment: maybe you can check multi thread module , like threading, _thread

Comment: You should be able to make an async task and then you can continue your main thread while the song thread continues to execute. Then you can create a loop calling and awaiting it to finish. Both the function containing the loop and the function being executed inside the loop (with an await) should be async. The loop will be paused awaiting completion of the awaitable, but the loop being async itself makes the main thread continue. If you need to stop the async task you need to use a context manager or similar to send it a signal. I would avoid threading at all costs... It's usually a bad idea

Comment: This image springs to mind with Multithreading https://bholley.net/images/posts/thistall.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You can try `mixer` from `pygame` module for playing sounds and repeat it infinitely in the 'background'.

```
import contextlib
with contextlib.redirect_stdout(None): # hide pygame intro text
    from pygame import mixer # import mixer from pygame module

mixer.init() # initialize the mixer module
mixer.music.load('songname.mp3') # load media file
mixer.music.set_volume(0.5) # set playing volume
mixer.music.play(-1) # play & loops media for n times in arguments, -1 always looping


# for demonstration
from random import randint, choice

def demo():
    a, b = randint(0,10), randint(0,10)
    while True:
        if int(input(f'{a} + {b} = ')) == a + b:
            print(choice(['Correct!', 'Nice!', 'Excellent!', 'Genius!', 'Wow!']))
            demo() if input('More (y/n)? ') == 'y' else print('Bye!'); break
        else:
            print(choice(['Wrong!', 'Nope!', 'OMG!', 'WTH!', 'Try Again!', 'LOL!']))


demo()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the native module [`threading`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html). Please refer to [this answer as guideline for non-blocking audio playback with threading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72733662/synchronization-for-video-audio-text-message-in-flask-web-app-framework-for-faci/73461559#73461559).

Answer (score -1):

subprocess forks then execs a process, but it waits for the process to finish before returning.  you will need to do this in a separate thread, use an asyncio suprocess interface or do an initial a fork yourself.  it is a bit tricky.  what is also complicated, is that you will likely not get a perfect gapless playback by looping subprocess commands, as python will likely take a millisecond or two to re-execute the command.